# How to force DTOs types to implement a method?

Tags: c#, oop

I want to implement a method like this with C# 7.3 to force some data transfer objects to comply with my implementation:

```
    public List<T> QueryOnDb<T>(DateTime dateRef) where T : baseDTO
    {
        string param = T.getParam();
        List<string> resultJson = _context.Foo.Where(x=> x.type == param).Select(x=> x.json).ToList();
        return resultJson.Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x)).ToList();
    }
```

Obviously it won't compile, because C# does not support static **abstract** methods on a abstract class.

The first workaround I tought was to pass param on the signature of QueryOnDb, but I could have T and param different.

EDIT 1: added the mention that `getParam()` should be abstrat.

Comment: _C# does not support static methods on a abstract class_ actually, it supports. Seems like, you've mixed generics with abstract classes. And there is no abstract class in your code

Comment: In version 8 or more it supports, doesn't on version 7.3.

I would like to get a method on a generic.

Comment: `public abstract class Temp { public static string GetSomething() { return "hi"; } }` ← perfectly legal c#. Abstract class with a static method. I do not think this was ever not supported in any version of the c# language spec.

Comment: oh! I forgot to say that the static member should also be abstract.

Comment: `public abstract class Temp { public abstract static string GetSomething();} }` won't compile. At least on my version of C#. And I don't want to update the project just because of this.

Comment: Maybe include what an implementation of `getParam` would look like.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use Reflection so that a call to a static method in a generic class will chain to a static method with a particular name in a derived class, if one exists, or use a programmed fallback action if none exists.  It's not possible to make the compiler reject derived classes that fail to define a static method with a particular name, but that's not really any more of a problem than the broader inability of compilers to reject classes that violate their inheritance requirements in most other ways.

Although Reflection has a reputation for being slow, performance can be quite good if a generic class uses a static delegate to identify the function to be called.  That delegate should be initialized to a function that will use Reflection to look up the static method in the class specified by the generic parameter, and store it in the delegate.  Future calls can then use that delegate directly without having to look up the method again for that particular generic class.

Comment: Is it possible at least to implement a test to force all derived of a baseclass to implement such method?